# scrape info from active directory profile

Tags: c#, active-directory

Looking for an API or something to start with so that I can pull the information contained in a users AD profile.

Not even sure how to start this so any direction on this is great.
Im pretty new to C# and this is totally alien to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do some searching here on Stack Overflow, you'll find plenty of material to help you in this direction. For example: [Get list of user in Active Directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13496650/get-list-of-user-in-active-directory).

To retrieve data for a single user, see [Quick way to retrieve user information Active Directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/456523/quick-way-to-retrieve-user-information-active-directory).

Comment: I see where you are going with this but I am more interested in getting all of the info for one user per query rather than all users with one query.

Does that make more sense?

Comment: I see your edited answer and this helps.

I just need to know how to take the data it finds, and then dumps it into my previously created text field (from my previous question you answered by the way :-)) So that I am pulling info from multiple locations and then puting them in one location for the user to see.

Comment: Would you like it with fries too?

Comment: I do not like french fries :-(

But you have provided me with a good start - its just tough when I have one question and the answer leads me to have 4 new questions after.

I guess if you follow me around enough you will have a ton of checkmarks by the end of this :-)

Comment: That is pretty normal. I didn't want to be rude or anything - I was just trying to show you that you need to do a lot of Googling in order to find the answers, and as you do that you will be able to fit the pieces together.

Comment: I actually spoke to one of our C# programmers here at the office. The answer was more simple than it sounded. I just needed to go into References and enable the two DLLs needed. 

    using System.DirectoryServices;
    using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;

Now I need to figure out how to search with it!

Comment: That's not the solution - it's just the starting point :) Yes you need to add those references to use the Active Directory APIs. Then you need to use the methods in it like in the links I posted.

Answer (score 1):

I recently completed a C# project using the

```
System.DirectoryServices
System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement
```

namespaces. The API is comprised of `Principals` which include things like computers, controllers and people, and it reveals search functions to scour the Active Directory for your parameters. It's an elegant API and it's really easy to jump into. Here's a link to get you started: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: I think you are on to what I am looking for.

But I have to be able to pull the info via a query. How would I be able to pull that?